# Google Sheet Add On serving html on new browser window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a **Google Sheets add-on** (not a Web App) and I want to generate an HTML page and show it in a new browser window. When I try to show the HTML page inside a Modal Dialog, it works. But when I try to show the same html content in another browser tab, I get an error message stating:

```
A server error has occurred. Wait a moment and try again.
```

This is the code that works, showing the html content insine a modal dialog:

```
function doTable() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('table')
  .setWidth(1400)
  .setHeight(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Simple analysis');
}
```

This is what is shown:

[image]

But I cannot figure out how to show the same content in a new browser window. :(

I tried this code, but without success:

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('table'); 
    html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    ss.show(html);
```

This too doesn't work:

```
return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('table')
      .evaluate()
       .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine for the method for correctly replicating your issue of `But when I try to show the same html content in another browser tab, I get an error message stating:`. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to serve HTML/JavaScript/CSS to a new web browser window from the Spreadsheet Service (Class SpreadsheetApp).

It's possible to use a use a Dialog / Sidebar client-side to open a URL in a new web browser tab / window, that URL might be the URL of a web app created using your add-on project. For this you will have to deploy a web-app.

Comment: Hi @Rúben, thank you! I was afraid that what I was trying to do was not possible.